# CSWP Paging Not Showing Up

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-search-web-part, paging

Paging is not showing up on my CSWP. I have a content search webpart getting items from an authoring site (cross-site publishing). There are currently 6 items in the catalog and the "number of items to show" set to 3 and only 3 items show up when the page is rendered. The catalog has been crawled and the query test in the CSWP is indeed showing all 6 items. I have the control set to display template set to:

**Control**: "List with Paging"

**Item**: "Two Lines"

These are the out of the box templates with no modifications. Any ideas why the paging is not showing up?

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue with the default SharePoint 2013 online Control_ListWithPaging.html file.  I uploaded a copy from our on-premise SharePoint 2013 environment to the SharePoint online Content Web Parts library. Now the list with paging option shows up in the CSWP.